# CF9 Error Executing Database Query

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting this error and don't understand why:

> **Error Executing Database Query**. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC
>   Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'buildno'.   The error occurred
>   in C:/data/wwwroot/webappsdev/cfeis/redbook/redbook_bio_load.cfm: line
>   10
>
> ```
>     8 :    select *
>     9 :   from redbook_bio
>     10 :       where build_num = '#session.build_num#'
>     11 : </cfquery>
>     12 :
> ```
>
> VENDORERRORCODE:    207
>  SQLSTATE:   42S22
>  SQL:       select * from
>   redbook_bio where buildno = '4700'
>  DATASOURCE: xxxx
>   **************"

It is saying `buildno` is an invalid column name, but I do not have that name in my query. I used to, but changed both the column in the database and the column name in the query to build_num. You can see my exact code with line numbers, and that there is no 'buildno' in there. But looking at the SQL statement below that, it is still trying to use 'buildno'.

I had my editor check the directory for anywhere it says `buildno` and no results came back. I have restarted the CF Service and cleared the cache. Why would it still be trying to run it with `buildno` instead of `build_num` like the code says?

Comment: Most likely because you are using `SELECT *`. I recall something similar on HOF. The *gist* was the sql or table metadata(?) was being cached as well. So until you clear cache, it still reflects the old columns.

Comment: Another little fix that I've found, is that if you go into the code, and add dbo.redbook_bio (or whatever prefix is applicable), OR, remove it if its already there, that will cause it to pull over a fresh look of the table/view.  There is probably some tiny performance loss with the method you accepted as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There was a cfquery cache setting in the Administrator. We had it set to 100. Apparently clearing the cache template and component cache doesn't clear the cfquery cache. I changed the query name and it fixed the problem. It most likely could have been fixed by setting the cfquery cache value to 0.

Comment: it would also be fixed by not using `SELECT *`. List out your column names.

Comment: Another trick to clear the cached CF query is to edit the query itself. I usually add an extra field or where 1=1 just for one time use. It seems that ColdFusion compares the exact sql stringto decide loading from cache or not. Or simply go to the basics and set or update the cachedwithin attribute of cfquery.